# How can I copy the current filename and line number to the clipboard?

Tags: os-clipboard

How can I copy the current file name and line number to the system clipboard, formatted like this:

`relative/path/to/file:123`

And how can I map this to a leader key command?

Answer (score 0):

The necessary command is `:let @+ = expand('%') . ':' . line(".")`

This can be mapped to a leader key command like this:

`:nmap <Leader>l <Esc>:let @+ = expand('%') . ':' . line(".")<CR>`

The equivalent in Lua for NeoVim is:

`set("n", "<Leader>l", ":let @+ = expand('%') . ':' . line('.')<cr>")`